# CakePHP: FormHelper not showing default values from associated model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

We have two models which are related by a has and belongs to many (HABTM) relationship: Jobs, Tests. We are able to add/edit the relationships successfully (we know because they show up in the join table), but we can't get the existing values to appear in the view. The select/checkboxes (we've tried both) are always empty.

Here are the model relationships:

```
//Job.php
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array (
    'Test' => array (
        'classname' => 'Test', 
        'foreignKey'=>'job_id',
        'joinTable' => 'jobs_tests',
        'associatedForeignKey' => 'test_id'
    )
);

//Test.php
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Job' => array(
            'className'=> 'Job',
            'joinTable'=>'jobs_tests',
            'foreignKey' => 'test_id',
            'associatedForeignKey'=> 'job_id'
            )

    );
```

Here is the /view/Jobs/edit.ctp

```
            echo $this->Form->select('Test', $test_options, array('class'=>'form-control', 'multiple'=>'checkbox'));
//This is always empty (nothing selected/checked).
```

What are we doing wrong?

**Update:**

Here is the JobsController action:

```
public function admin_edit( $id=NULL ) {
    $this->layout = 'admin';
    if (!$id)
        $this->redirect( array('controller'=>'jobs', 'action'=>'index'));

    $this->loadModel('Company');
    $companies = $this->Company->find('all');
    $company_options = array();
    foreach ($companies as $company) {
        $company_options[ $company['Company']['id'] ] = $company['Company']['name'];
    }
    $this->set('company_options', $company_options);

    $this->loadModel('Test');
    $tests = $this->Test->find('all');
    $tests_options = array();
    foreach ($tests as $test) {
        $test_options[ $test['Test']['id'] ] = $test['Test']['name'];
    }
    $this->set('test_options', $test_options);

    $category_options = $this->Job->validCategories;

    $this->set('category_options', $category_options);

    if ($this->request->isPut() ) {
        $data = $this->request->data;
        //debug($data);exit;
        $save = $this->Job->save( $data );
        if ($save) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Job edited');
            //$job = $this->Job->findById( $id );
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error editting job');
        }


    } 

    $job = $this->Job->findById($id);
    $this->request->data = $job;
    $this->set('job', $job);
}
```

Here is the form in the admin_edit.ctp view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Job'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type'=>'hidden'));
            echo $this->Form->input('name', array('class'=>'form-control')); 
            echo $this->Form->input('email', array('class'=>'form-control'));
            echo $this->Form->input('location', array('class'=>'form-control'));

            echo '<label>Type</label>';
            echo $this->Form->select('type', array('FT'=>'Full Time', 'PT'=>'Part Time', 'IN'=>'Internship'), array('empty'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control'));

            echo '<label>Company</label>';
            echo $this->Form->select('company_id', $company_options, array('class'=>'form-control')); 
            echo $this->Form->input('short_description', array('label' => 'Short Description', 'class'=>'form-control'));
            echo $this->Form->input('full_description', array('type'=>'textarea', 'label' => 'Full Description', 'class'=>'form-control'));
            echo $this->Form->input('is_private', array('label'=>'Is Private?', 'class'=>'form-control') );

            echo '<label>Category</label>';
            echo $this->Form->select('category', $category_options, array('class'=>'form-control'));
            echo '<label>Tests</label>';            
            //echo $this->Form->select('Test.id', $test_options, array('class'=>'form-control', 'multiple'=>true));

            $selected = array();
            foreach ($job['Test'] as $test) {
                $selected[]=$test['id'];
                //$selected[ $test['id'] ] = $test['name'];
            }
            debug($selected);
            echo $this->Form->input('Test', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$test_options, 'class'=>'form-control', 'multiple'=>'checkbox', 'selected'=>$selected));
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Comment: On a side note, it's `associationForeignKey`, not `associatedForeignKey`, but it's not necessary to define these values when following the conventions, as CakePHP will then pick the correct names automatically.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you are making your life way more complicated then necessary, and that'll always lose your input in case the form cannot be saved as you are always overwriting it (Is that maybe your problem? Losing the selections after submitting the form?), I can't see why it shouldn't work, assuming `$test_data` and `$selected` do contain the expected data. That being said, it would be helpful to see what exactly they contain.

Comment: @ndm An example of $test_data: `array(
 (int) 0 => '5',
 (int) 1 => '7'
)
`. The data is not lost after submission. The defaults/current selections all appear fine. Only the HABTM association is problematic.

Comment: Sorry, I ment `$test_options`, not `$test_data`. Also it looks like you are showing the contents of `$selected`, as `$test_options` should be in `id => name` format according to your controller code?

Comment: @ndm I was confused too. What I just sent was $test_options, but we have also tried with the key=>value version: `array(
 (int) 5 => 'WSAT Practice',
 (int) 7 => 'WSAT-PE'
)
` and that also did not work. As for the matter of the data being reset... I don't think that is actually happening because I debug it in the view and all the data is there (including associations). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHEW! This was a stumper but the solution turned out to be simple... The values in $options['selected'] were strings (of numbers), which was confusing CakePHP. We converted them to ints using `intval()` and it works perfectly now, using *all* the original settings...

Here's the revised version of what is in the view (notice the `intval()`):

```
        $selected = array();
        foreach ($job['Test'] as $test) {
            $selected[]= intval($test['id']);
        }
         echo $this->Form->input('Test', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$test_options, 'class'=>'form-control', 'multiple'=>'checkbox', 'selected'=>$selected));
```

Also, as a sidenote, this is evidence that pretty much everything that was challenged in the comments above works completely fine:

1. `$options['selected']` does *not* need to be key=>value pairs.
2. The pattern we're using does *not* overwrite the request->data and passes the data to the form helper just fine.
3. non-camelCased variable names passed to the view ($some_variable_name) are still picked up correctly by the form helper.

Hopefully this comes in handy to someone else.

Comment: **1.** Nobody said that would be the case, of course it's _the options data_ that needs to be in `key => value` format. **2.** It _does_ by `$this->request->data = $job;`, and in case the data cannot be saved you'll lose your input as it's being overwritten with the data fetched from the DB. **3.** Nobody was trying to prove the contrary... though it's not completely true as it stands, you can _explicitly_ pass whatever variable you want to the Form helper, but _auto-pickup_ of view variables belonging to `hasMany`/`HABTM` associated models requires proper camel cased plural variable names.

Comment: Not everything, but some of it, yes. You are explicitly passing the view variables to the Form helper, which in your case is necessary as it wouldn't auto-pick it up since that would require following the mentioned naming conventions.

Comment: @ndm I'm interested to try it without having to manually pass the $options['selected']. Can you show me a snippet that would allow that?

Comment: Check my previous comments, I've linked to the docs that explain how it works, there's also an example (it's just two lines of code, one in the controller, one in the view): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842987/cakephp-formhelper-not-showing-default-values-from-associated-model/19869241#comment29511534_19843743

Answer (score 0):

What if you pass set the default values using Model::find('list').

```
//controller
$this->set('test_options', $this->YourModel->find('list'));


//view
 echo $this->Form->select('Test', $test_options, array('class'=>'form-control', 'multiple'=>'checkbox'));
```

Comment: Yea. This would work but it feels a bit "analogue". Aside from the hassle of manually setting the default values, I'm concerned that this implies something wrong with our model associations. PS: I think you missed the 'values'=>... array in your code.

Comment: @Emerson There's nothing wrong with that, actually you _must_ pass the values to the view, CakePHP won't do that automatically for you. But when doing so you should stick to the conventions, and that means, set the values in a variable with the lowercase plural model name, ie `tests`, and use `FormHelper::input()`, that way the Form helper can pick up the data and check the necessary values automatically. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla You might want to update your answer accordingly.

Comment: I edited the code, thanks.

@Emerson what if you don't set manually the default values but keep the find call in the way I told you?

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla I haven't tried `find('list')` yet, but I did try sticking the Test.id(s) into a `$test_options` array and setting the `'default'=>$test_options` and that didn't work either. Also, I'm confused by some of what you said about always having to set the defaults manually. It's not true. We don't set the default values manually anywhere else on the form and it works fine. CakePHP looks at `$this->request->default()` and populates

Comment: @Emerson Are you actually replying to _me_? What I said is true, it won't work automatically for `hasMany` and `HABTM` associations, if it works for you in other places without passing a list of values for the helper, then please update your question and show how you've managed that, nobody here knows what's inside this magical `$test_options` variable and where it comes from. Also note that by default the request only contains data after the form was submitted, so maybe you also want to elaborate a little further under which circumstances your problem appears.

Comment: @ndm Oops I was replying to your comment but I think I understood what you meant now about "passing values to the view". That is what we are doing via the $request->data, and it works without overtly setting the 'default' option (but only for the non-HABTM data). The $test_options array is just an array of ids: `array('23', '43', '53'...)` The IDs correspond to the `value` attribute in the select options.

Comment: @Emerson It should be an array in `key => value` format, just like `Model::find('list')` returns, where the key is the ID, and the value whatever you want to display as the label, otherwise it would use the default array indices (starting at 0) for matching against the associated records IDs. But let's stop stabbing in the dark, please add the controller action code and the rest of the form code to your question.

Comment: @ndm I tried setting the default as a key=>value pair also and had no luck, but maybe I did something wrong. I've added the controller action and form from the view above. Thanks for your help.